# Smith normal form of rectangular matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matrices, matlab, matrix-decomposition, smith-normal-form

Suppose I've got a nonsquare integer matrix, say $\begin{pmatrix}3 & 1 & 1 & 1\\1 & 1 & 1 &1\end{pmatrix}$ and want to compute its Smith normal form--in this case, $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 2 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. Is there an easy way to do this in MATLAB's symbolic toolbox? Its function for computing SNF requires invertible arguments.

Comment: I will note that I've used https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/60410 with some success. I'm hoping for a way to leverage MATLAB's smithForm directly though.

Comment: Also handy is http://www.numbertheory.org/php/smith.html